# onActivityResult does not get result ? +schema

Tags: android, android-fragments, startactivityforresult

From some `Fragment` I call an `Activity` like this:

```
private void setEmailChangeListener() {
    emailChangeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EmailChangeActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

    });
}
```

In that `Activity` I make some changes to e-mail in database and then update info in local database (updated e-mail and update time and date). Then I call `setResult`:

```
     if (!error) {
       JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                                    String updatedAt = user.getString("updated_at");

       String userUniqueId = db.getUserUniqueId();
       db.updateUpdatedAt(updatedAt, userUniqueId);

       Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
       finish();
} else {
       String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
       showSnackbarInfo(errorMsg, R.color.snackbar_error);
}
```

In `Activity` with opened `Fragment` I want to update info in `Fragment` by `detach` and `attach` in order to refrsh it. I do it in `onActivityResult` like this:

```
// Result From Other Activities
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        Log.i("result", "reqCode = 1, zmieniam adres email w nav draw i odswierzam fragment");
        navHeaderEmail.setText(db.getEmailAdress());
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                TAG_FRAGMENT_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.attach(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        showSnackbarInfo(getString(R.string.inf_email_change_success),
                R.color.snackbar_success);
    }
}
```

After calling `setResult` nothing happens just like I didn't set the result properly or something else. Could you help me with this?

Here is schema how it should work:

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Home Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/application_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Normal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Login Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_activity_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Logreg">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Sign Up Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/register_activity_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Logreg">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Email Change Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".EmailChangeActivity"
            android:label="@string/change_email_activity_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Normal">
        </activity>

        <!-- Password Change Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordChangeActivity"
            android:label="@string/change_password_activity_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Normal">
        </activity>

        <!-- Recipe Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".RecipeActivity"
            android:label="@string/recipe_activity_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Normal">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How is declared your activity inside your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @Elenasys please check my Edited answer :)

Comment: Maybe some ideas cause I have none why it does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

or override onActivityResult in the fragment it self

I had the problem in reverse I was trying to use onActivityResult inside my fragment but sometimes it went to the parent activity so I ended up using the first line and handling it in the parent actvity

Comment: It wors very well now! Thank you for help :) So all you haad to do was to give `getActtivity` to get activity context :)